# Audio stops on phone lock

Tags: 8.1, audio

I have been experiencing this weird issue now-a-days(After update to Cyan, Nokia Lumia 625-unlocked) where audio files received using WhatsApp stop playing as soon as the phone auto-locks. In other words, when I receive an audio file, about 3 minutes long, and start playing it; the phone locks after 1 minute that is set as the screen timeout for me and the audio stops. I have to start playing it from the very beginning every time that happens.

I notice a similar behaviour when I play audio files directly from "Files" app. However, any music played from the music app and podcasts app etc plays normally.

ETA: I tried updating the maps for the device and observed that the download terminated as soon as the screen timed out. If the 2 different problems are correlated, this might indicate something to do with background tasks.

Comment: Did this happen when running 8.0 (ie. pre-Cyan)?

Comment: @NeilTurner I don't think so. I am not actually sure.

Comment: The reason I ask is that WP8 app should run exactly the same on WP8.1 - if they didn't, most apps would have serious issues.

Answer (score 2):

This is a general behavior.

When the app runs under a locked screen, it could **consume power** outside of the user's control and could add to their **data costs** without their awareness. So the app must remain idle while the phone screen is locked. And that is why we see "Resuming..." when we lock the phone while using an app(i.e. WhatsApp, WeChat, Voxer, etc.) and unlock it again.

Comment: Have you tried playing an audio and letting the screen lock? I have access to 2 other handsets running the same versions of WhatsApp and the OS and the audio keeps running after the lock in both of them. It doesn't in mine, hence the question. And how about the maps download?

Comment: Wow... This is strange... For me the audio stops and I am back to the WhatsApp Chat page.

Comment: What devices do you use?

Comment: Nokia Lumia 625

Comment: At least that gives an indication that I am not alone!!

Comment: For me, The audio files that I received on WhatsApp never played in the background.

Comment: On all other handsets of the same configuration they do, and thats why I asked. I wonder how and why that varies!

Comment: Have you checked Battery Saver? Have allowed WhatsApp to run in background?

Comment: Most certainly. WhatApp is about the only application thats allowed. I tried allowing Music as well when I got into the above issue, but there was no change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16243/discussion-between-vaibhav-garg-and-vivek-parekh).

Comment: Were the other, background playing, phones also 625s?

Comment: An 1) app running in the background and updating its Live Tile and 2) running while the phone is locked are two different things, btw - what other handsets did you try this on, all Lumia 625s?

Comment: @NeilTurner, 2 of them were 625s. One was a 620.

Comment: @RowlandShaw, pls see the above comment.

Comment: Although the answer does not resolve the issue, I appreciate that enough interest and help was demonstrated by the answerer; and therefore I am awarding the bounty to him.

Comment: I tried to allow radio/FM to run in background.it working fine...njoy guys

Comment: Make fm run in bckgrnd